# In React unable to use array of objects in search filter

Tags: reactjs, json

At the moment I'm attempting to adapt `react-searh-autocomplete` to my purposes. I'm specifically having a problem with searching against the data set I get back from my server. And I can see a difference in structure. However, I can't figure out how to convert / fix this.

### Server results

As displayed in the console from a `console.log(currentNarratives)`

```
Array (1124)
0 {id: 4014, scheduled: 0, date: "2025-02-09", ongoing: null, title: "Super Bowl LIX"}
1 {id: 4013, scheduled: 0, date: "2024-02-11", ongoing: null, title: "Super Bowl LVIII"}
2 {id: 4012, scheduled: 1, date: "2023-02-12", ongoing: null, title: "Super Bowl LVII"}
```

### Data in original example

```
  const items = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Cobol'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'JavaScript'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Basic'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'PHP'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Java'
    }
  ]
```

And in the console:
[image]

And when doing a `typeof` for both `items` and `currentNarratives` the result is `Object`.

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:
`items = currentNarratives`

### Search Component

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './search.css'
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from 'react-search-autocomplete'
import { getNarratives } from '../../requests/requests';



function Search() {
    const [narrativesState, setNarrativesState] = useState({narratives: []});
    const narratives = narrativesState

    useEffect(() => {

                    const narratives = getNarratives().then(response => {
                        //console.log(response);
                        setNarrativesState({narratives:response});
                        //console.log(narrativesState.narratives)
                        })

                },
                    //pull canonicalurl
                    //send to performsearch

             [])

    const currentNarratives = narrativesState.narratives?.sort((a, b) => a.date < b.date ? 1 : -1)
    let datesarray = []

    // convert object to key's array
    //  Object.keys(data).forEach(val => console.log(val));
    Object.values(currentNarratives).forEach(narrative =>{
    !datesarray.includes(narrative.date) && datesarray.push(narrative.date)

    });

    datesarray.sort((date1, date2) => (-date1.localeCompare(date2)));




    //const items = currentNarratives


  const items = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Cobol'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'JavaScript'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Basic'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'PHP'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Java'
    }
  ]
    console.log(currentNarratives)
    console.log(items)
  const handleOnSearch = (string, results) => {
    // onSearch will have as the first callback parameter
    // the string searched and for the second the results.

    console.log(string, results)
  }

  const handleOnHover = (result) => {
    // the item hovered
    console.log(result)
  }

  const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
    // the item selected
    console.log(item)
  }

  const handleOnFocus = () => {
    console.log('Focused')
  }

  const formatResult = (item) => {
    return item
    // return (<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<strong>'+item+'</strong>'}}></p>); //To format result as html
  }

  return (
    <div >

        <div >
          <ReactSearchAutocomplete
            items={items}
            onSearch={handleOnSearch}
            onHover={handleOnHover}
            onSelect={handleOnSelect}
            onFocus={handleOnFocus}
            autoFocus
            formatResult={formatResult}
          />
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed this by converting the object array to a json array like so:

```
    var cnJson = []

    currentNarratives.map(function(item) {
       cnJson.push({
            "id" : item.id,
            "name"  : item.title
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fuseOptions={{
          keys: ["title"],
        }}
```